# Incorrect width of the div but the height is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that I can't get correct width.

css of div:

```
.child {
    background-color: green;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 200px 100px 20px;
}
```

I get width, height, x and y like this, where
`refComponent = React.createRef();`

```
const current = me.refComponent.current
if (current != null) {
    this.setState({
        width: current.getBoundingClientRect().width,
        height: current.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        x: current.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y: current.getBoundingClientRect().top
    });
}
```

I'm attaching a picture in which you can see that height is correct, but width is not, and x of div is also incorrect (y is correct)

[image]